# Heroku war:deploy - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: java, heroku

I have a project at Heroku where I use JAVA 10, SPRING BOOT, GRADLE.

My Procfile: `web: java -jar build/server/webapp-runner-*.jar build/libs/*.war`

My system.properties: `java.runtime.version=10`

I generated my app.war locally using `gradle bootWar` with success.

After that, I deployed my app.war using

```
heroku war:deploy ./build/libs/app.war --app app-dev
```

I received no errors during the deploy, it was like a success, but when I saw my project logs, there was this error:

```
2019-02-15T02:38:42.796193+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar webapp-runner.jar ${WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS} --port 49161 ./build/libs/app.war`
2019-02-15T02:38:46.173244+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2019-02-15T02:38:46.177681+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2019-02-15T02:38:46.841993+00:00 app[web.1]: Expanding app.war into /app/target/tomcat.49161/webapps/expanded
2019-02-15T02:38:46.842041+00:00 app[web.1]: Adding Context  for /app/target/tomcat.49161/webapps/expanded
2019-02-15T02:38:47.269581+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:38:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
2019-02-15T02:38:47.269593+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-49161"]
2019-02-15T02:38:47.293324+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:38:47 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
2019-02-15T02:38:47.293328+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2019-02-15T02:38:47.309720+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:38:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2019-02-15T02:38:47.309724+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-02-15T02:38:47.310472+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:38:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2019-02-15T02:38:47.310475+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.38
2019-02-15T02:38:47.708137+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-15T02:38:47.652845+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:38:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
2019-02-15T02:38:47.652860+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No global web.xml found
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858030+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:38:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858034+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858036+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858037+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858039+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858041+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858043+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858045+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858046+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858047+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858049+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858050+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858052+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858053+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858055+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858056+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858058+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 6 more
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858060+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [org_apache_jasper] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
2019-02-15T02:38:47.858061+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2200)
...
2019-02-15T02:41:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user user@gmail.com
2019-02-15T02:41:42.591161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-02-15T02:41:42.407778+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user user@gmail.com
2019-02-15T02:41:42.407778+00:00 app[api]: Deploy e565bff0 by user user@gmail.com
2019-02-15T02:41:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-02-15T02:41:49.312253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar webapp-runner.jar ${WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS} --port 47389 ./build/libs/app.war`
2019-02-15T02:41:51.968104+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2019-02-15T02:41:51.972649+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2019-02-15T02:41:53.183680+00:00 app[web.1]: Expanding app.war into /app/target/tomcat.47389/webapps/expanded
2019-02-15T02:41:53.183878+00:00 app[web.1]: Adding Context  for /app/target/tomcat.47389/webapps/expanded
2019-02-15T02:41:54.343385+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:41:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
2019-02-15T02:41:54.343399+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-47389"]
2019-02-15T02:41:54.374799+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:41:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
2019-02-15T02:41:54.374804+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2019-02-15T02:41:54.486332+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:41:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2019-02-15T02:41:54.486337+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-02-15T02:41:54.488366+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:41:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2019-02-15T02:41:54.488369+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.38
2019-02-15T02:41:54.926789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-15T02:41:55.309038+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:41:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
2019-02-15T02:41:55.309053+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No global web.xml found
2019-02-15T02:41:55.510365+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 15, 2019 2:41:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
2019-02-15T02:41:55.510370+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
2019-02-15T02:41:55.510372+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
```

What is the cause of this error?

Does anyone have any idea to solve this error?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: do you get the same error with the command `heroku war:run`?

Comment: @codefinger, with ```heroku war:run``` my project starts without errors.

Comment: What does `java -version` show locally?

Comment: ```java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)```

Comment: Do you have a web.xml you can share?

Comment: I'm not using web.xml in my project

Comment: @codefinger, I made some experience, I generated the app.war by windows (Same PC), made deploy using the windows too and everything was a successful. So, I got the exactly app.war that I generated by windows and I tried to deploy by ubuntu and the same error occurred. So, the problem is in the heroku war:deploy running by ubuntu. Do you have any idea of what could be this problem? In the windows I'm using oracle jdk 10 and in the ubuntu I'm using openjdk 10. Could it be a problem with openjdk version?

Comment: @codefinger, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem too.
After some trials and errors I found out that dependency on webapp-runner was included twice:

1. As a part of maven-dependency-plugin plugin. This is a working example by Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner.
2. As a general project dependency.

Removing the second reference (general dependency) to webapp-runner solved the issue.
Though Gradle uses a bit different semantics from Maven, I guess the idea is the same.